# Chrome Extension:How to show background image in new Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am willing to have a similar functionality like given in popular extensions like Moments or Limitless which show beautiful wallpaper.

How can I implement it? Also, if multiple similar extensions are installed who shows image on new tab, is there way to let chrome show my image in tab first?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible by indicating a different new tab page in the `chrome_url_overrides` property in the `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "myNewTabPage.html"
  }
}
```

Then you can modify the `myNewTabPage.html` with background image you need, attaching the necessary stylesheets and assets.

[Check here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) more details about overrides.

*If multiple similar extensions are installed* The new tab override will be managed by the latest extension installed on Chrome and this behavior cannot be changed.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Kind of *sad* to know I can't set order of loading page in new tab. In order to load stuff like JQuery, Bootstrap etc. I just call them within that page as we do in normal pages or do I have to mention in manifest?

Comment: Yes, you can include any scripts, stylesheets and assets within the custom new tab page.

Comment: I know it is old but when I try to set image via Javascript it does not work. It does not show image at all